# matplotlib claims I have an outdated version of six

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror, six

I just set up a conda environment for an api but when I try to run it I get a strange error with matplotlib 2.2.2:

```
ImportError: Matplotlib requires six>=1.10; you have 1.9.0
```

Seems like a simple error but a look at my conda list shows that I have version 1.11.0 of six installed. I am absolutely certain that these packages are installed in the same environment and are being accessed properly. I can't find any reference to six 1.9.0 in the my environment or even my machine. Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: It may help to `import six`, and then check these attributes: `six.__version__` and `six.__file__`

Comment: Weird, I did this and PyCharm says I have version 1.9.0. However, both my project interpreter settings and my conda list say I have version 1.11.0. Where is this older version coming from?

Comment: If youre running it from a terminal, it's probably the system version of python instead of the conda version. Try updating six with pip (`pip install six` or `pip install six --user`).

Comment: I'm trying to run in both the terminal and PyCharm and pip installation doesn't seem to affect either.

Comment: Try to give more informat inside the question about how you run things and what print statements result in which output. The more details people have about what exact steps you are using, the higher the chances for you to get a useful hint or answer.

Comment: `six.__file__` should have told you where the package is. You can probably figure out which environment you're in from that, and update that environment accordingly. I'm not sure how much more help we can be without knowing anything else about your problem.

Comment: Oh yes, this thread has been immensely helpful. Thank you. I'll see what I can find with the information given.